# How to redirect from an authenticator to an external authentication endpoint?

Tags: authentication, cakephp, openid-connect

I'm writing a web app which I want to have flexible authentication options due to different customers' needs.  I'm using the official [cakephp/authentication](https://github.com/cakephp/authentication) library, but it doesn't have an OpenID Connect Authenticator, so I'm rolling my own.

The problem I'm having is that I can't return a modified `Cake\Http\Response` object with a redirect header from my Authenticator.  `AuthenticatorInterface` requires the `authenticate()` method to return a `Result` object.  I'm hoping to not have to modify more than the Authenticator class, because it kind of defeats the purpose of using the library if I'm just going to rewrite it's flow.

```
class OidcAuthenticator extends AbstractAuthenticator
{
public function authenticate(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response)
{
    // non-pertinent code removed for brevity
    return $this->_requestAuthorization($request, $response);
}


private function _requestAuthorization(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response)
{
    $auth_endpoint = $this->getConfig('authorization_endpoint');
    $response_type = 'code';
    $state = $this->_setState($request, Security::randomString());

    $auth_params = [
        'response_type' => $response_type,
        'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost:8080/',
        'client_id' => $this->getConfig('client_id'),
        'nonce' => $nonce,
        'state' => $state,
        'scope' => 'openid'
    ];

    $auth_endpoint .= (strpos($auth_endpoint, '?') === false ? '?' : '&') .
        http_build_query($auth_params, null, '&');

    /* What I want to return */
    $response = $response->withHeader('Location', $auth_endpoint);

    /* What I have to return */
    return new Result(null, Result::FAILURE_MISSING_CREDENTIALS);
}
}
```

I can make this work with

```
$request->getAttribute('session')->close();
header('Location: ' . $auth_endpoint, true, 302);
exit();
```

but that seems to violate CakePHP conventions.  Ideally, I could embed the new response object into the Result and the Authentication middleware would catch it and emit it instead of the `UnauthenticatedException`.  This is kind of a best-practices question, but hopefully it's specific enough for SO.

TL;DR: How to redirect when you can't return a response object to the middleware queue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAICT there isn't really a recommended practice for now, it might be worth opening an issue [**over at GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/authentication/issues) for clarification.

You could make use of `AuthenticationRequiredException` (or `UnauthorizedException` in earlier versions), it's kinda tangled with stateless authentication, but there's nothing that would stop you from using it. Unlike stateless authenticators you'd have to throw it in the `authenticate()` method call flow, something like this:

```
private function _requestAuthorization(
    ServerRequestInterface $request,
    ResponseInterface $response
) {
    // ...

    $headers = [
        'Location' => $auth_endpoint
    ];
    $body = null;
    $statusCode = 302;

    // in CakePHP 4.x / Authentication 2.x
    throw new \Authentication\Authenticator\AuthenticationRequiredException (
        $headers,
        $body,
        $statusCode
    );

    // in CakePHP 3.x / Authentication 1.x
    throw new \Authentication\Authenticator\UnauthorizedException(
        $headers,
        $body,
        $statusCode
    );
}
```

This will then be handled in [**`AuthenticationMiddleware::__invoke()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/authentication/blob/2.3.0/src/Middleware/AuthenticationMiddleware.php#L106-L116) accordingly, where the response will be modified and returned.

Comment: This looks great!  I’m AFK at the moment, but when I get back I’ll try it and mark answered.

Comment: Works perfectly!  I've marked the question as answered and posted an issue (#231) over on GitHub as you suggested.  Thanks for your help!