# How to enforce redirect from Subclass in Cakephp

Tags: authentication, cakephp, keycloak, cakephp-4.x

I want to authenticate against Keycloak from a Cake app using the [Auth-Middleware](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/2/en/index.html). I mocked it in AppController which worked out well, and I am pretty sure that it's going to work with the middleware as well. I wrote 2 new Authenticator and 1 Identifier class for that

However, there is a problem I didn't see: I need to redirect to the keycloak instance from one of the Authenticator classes. I tried to throw `UnauthenticatedException`, but get an error, that `Authentication is required to continue`.

The exception throw wasn't my fav anyway, as it seemed difficult to store the state for csrf protection that way.

So: could anyone advice me how to redirect from inside an Authenticator class?

Comment: I can't test it right now, but I think this should be still valid in 4.x, except that the exception has been renamed to `AuthenticationRequiredException`: **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54067100/how-to-properly-redirect-from-a-cakephp-authentication-authenticator-for-openid/54067364#54067364**

Comment: Thanks a lot .. the renamed Exception was the problem ..